# Getting a mean from a portion of a column in a data frame

Tags: r

I've got problems with trying to find a mean of a section of a column in a data frame.
The first thing I have run into is that the mean as to be a specific part of the data in the column.
I do not know how to get R to do this.

The second thing I need to set a marker in the column, as i then need to subtract the mean from the rest of the data, but the marker changes based on what data.frame I'm looking at.

Ive linked the [data file](https://unicanberraedu-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/u3164969_uni_canberra_edu_au/ETpGjWutKGFNtOg0-yJB-2UBq-8EXAOIhkl0yQY5UVlPqQ?e=iDoBO5). the section that I wanted to find the mean of is from sample 1-168, before the number resets back to 1. When the number resets is the point i need to start subtracting the mean from

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: For clarification: 1. The mean of what? `Sample aX     aY     az      Temp    gX     gY     gz`. 2. The first 4 rows of your dataframe have strange ids  `6525, 6526, 6527, 6526`. Can we delete this four rows. Then the first part to calculate the mean would consist of 1-163. Is that ok? In essence we can split the dataframe and do the calculations. Please be more specific to get adequate support.

Comment: Its kinda hard to explain, but yes the first four rows can be deleted. I have no idea how to create it so i cant produce an example

Comment: and please mean of which variable? temp?

Comment: i need to find the mean of aX aY and aZ. Ive made a data set to remove Temp gX gY and gZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is a try for the `Temp`column:

1. Load your data

```
# load data
library(readr)
# Data 1.txt is in project folder
Data_1 <- read_csv("./Data 1.txt", col_names = FALSE) 
View(Data_1)
```

2. Tweak data

```
#assign row 5 as colnames
colnames(Data_1) <- Data_1[5,] 

# remove row 1:5 
Data_1 <- Data_1[c(-1:-5),] 
View(Data_1)
```

3. Split dataframe `Data_1` in `df1` rows 1:163 and calculate the mean of `Temp`
   = -1673.325

```
df1 <- Data_1 %>% 
  slice(1:163) %>% 
  mutate(Temp = as.numeric(Temp), na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  summarise(Mean_Temp = mean(Temp), na.rm=TRUE)
```

4. Substract `Mean_Temp` from `Temp` in `df2` rows 164:n

```
df2 <- Data_1 %>% 
  slice(-1:-164) %>% 
  mutate(Temp = as.numeric(Temp)) %>% 
  mutate(Diff_meanTemp = Temp - df1$Mean_Temp, na.rm=TRUE)
```